# Asmx receiving POST -ed values(params) from Extjs?

Tags: web-services, post, extjs, ado.net, asmx

How to receive posted values to variable in .asmx that was posted from extjs, so it can be saved using ado.net to database?

**SENDING DATA WITH EXT.AJAX**

```
{
    text: 'Add',
    formBind: true,
    disabled: true,
    handler: function () {

        var form = this.up('form').getForm();
        var formValues = form.getValues();

        var firstName = formValues.firstName;
        var lastName = formValues.lastName;

        if (form.isValid()) {

            Ext.Ajax.request({

                url: 'WebServices/WebService.asmx/AddAgent',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                method: 'POST',
                jsonData: { FirstName: firstName, LastName: lastName }


            });
        }
    }
}
```

When submited, firebug reports error: 
[image]
How to properly recieve this values in .asmx so they can be used in [WebMethod] and saved with Ado.Net?

```
    [Serializable]
    public class Agents
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }


    //CREATE
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)]

    public string AddAgent()
    {
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AgentsServices"].ConnectionString; 

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into Agent(id, firstName, lastName) values(@id, @firstName, @lastName)", connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", FirstName); //here i get message( The name "FirstNAme does not exist in current context")
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", LastName); // -||-

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }       
    }
```

EDIT:

No. stil 500 Internal Server Error:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your web method doesn't seem to take any argument. Also your method expects to return a string and yet you do not return anything. So either return something or modify your method signature to `void`. Also you have set `UseHttpGet = true` and yet you are sending a POST request. Try like this:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public void AddAgent(Agents agents)
{
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AgentsServices"].ConnectionString; 
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into Agent(id, firstName, lastName) values(@id, @firstName, @lastName)", connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", agents.FirstName);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", agents.LastName);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }       
}
```

Also since you have defined the Id property of your Agents model as a non-nullable integer I would recommend you sending a value for it:

```
jsonData: { agents: { Id: 0, FirstName: firstName, LastName: lastName } }
```

Comment: @Ingol, answer updated, try passing the agents parameter name in the JSON: `jsonData: { agents: { Id: 0, FirstName: firstName, LastName: lastName } }`