# How to use Ext.data.writer.Json of Ext-js 4?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have codes reading JSON data from server by a proxy.

But how to write back new data using `Ext.data.writer.Json`? Any example?

I have a grid pannel associated with a store, which has a proxy I said beyond.

I'll put some code if you need to check out.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to see witch technology would fit your needs, i use .net webservices to communicate with GUI, here is a example of [this!](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/ExtJS__WebServices.aspx) Then you can use ado.net to communicate with database and save data you have send with web service, here is an example of [this!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867491/asmx-receiving-post-ed-valuesparams-from-extjs) There are other ways but this one works for me! Cheers!

Comment: I have a server script running on a server, though not .NET. And the problem I met is I don't know how is the `Ext.data.writer.Json` working and how to use it. I saw your example but I can only see store, proxy.